# Launch Intent on tap of Print button

Tags: android, printing

I would like to ask if it is possible to launch an `Intent` when I tap the `default Print button` (`chrome`, `google drive`, etc) in `Android 4.4 KitKat`?

I would like to perform certain functions when the `Print button` is tapped.

Comment: Nope i guess u can't because it is OS defined.We can't take any privilege on system defined Resources. i guess

Comment: Will I be able to know if the Print button was tapped?